# [noob]how to create two functions where second one doing the calculation?

Tags: codeblocks

i wrote the following code.
its basically enter 5 variables(a, b, c, f_a, f_b)
and calculate f_c= f_a + (f_b-f_a)*(c-a)/(b-a)

in the main function, i declared and scan all variables,
then i calculate the X, which is equal to f_c.

The question is how can i move the calculation of X to second function calculateFreezingTemp.

I tried to create a function f_c with 5 variables, failed.

```
double calculateFreezingTemp(double);

int main(void)
{double a, f_a, b, f_b, c, f_c, x;

printf("Please enter the data point A\n");
scanf("%lf %lf", &a, &f_a);

printf("Please enter the data point B\n");
scanf("%lf %lf", &b, &f_b);

printf("Please enter the salinity value between %f and %f\n", a, b);
scanf("%lf", &c);

x = f_a + ((c-a)/(b-a))*(f_b-f_a);

f_c = calculateFreezingTemp(x);

printf("For salinity %f ppt, Freezing Temperature is: %f\t",c, f_c);}

double calculateFreezingTemp(double x)
{double f_c;

f_c=x;

return(f_c);

}
```

Comment: "Failed"? Please elaborate. What did you do exactly, and what exactly went wrong?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what failed, add tell us in your question what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: too many variables in calculateFreezingTemp(double x),

Comment: it says too many argument to function calculateFreezingTemp if i replace x with a, b, c...etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the input variables to the 'calculateFreezingTemp' function:

```
f_c = calculateFreezingTemp(a, b, c, f_a, f_b)
```

and move the calculation into the function:

```
double calculateFreezingTemp(double a, double b, double c, double f_a, double f_b)
{
    return f_a + (f_b-f_a)*(c-a)/(b-a);
}
```

Comment: That's because you have to adjust the line where you first declare the function...
change the first line to: `calculateFreezingTemp(double a, double b, double c, double f_a, double f_b);`